# remoteControlReceived(with event: UIEvent?) Doesn't triggered

Tags: ios, swift, headset

I have audio recording/playing app. But I want to pause playing, when user uses play/pause button on the regular wired iPhone headset.
So i implemented handling of remote events:

```
// MARK: Overrides
internal extension AppDelegate {
    override func remoteControlReceived(with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.remoteControlReceived(with: event)
        /* some other logic */
    }
}
```

Then I started receiving remote events in `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    application.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
    becomeFirstResponder()
    /* some other logic */
    return true
}
```

But anyway `remoteControlReceived(with event: UIEvent?)` is never triggered.

Also I tried MPRemoteCommandCenter:

```
MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared().togglePlayPauseCommand.addTarget { (event) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in
    return .success
}
```

Doesn't triggered.

Swift or objective-c answers accepted :)

What is wrong? Or should I add something in .plist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the reason.... I'm using my app to mix it's sound with other apps, so I'm activating audio session with `mixWithOthers` option:

```
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, with: [.mixWithOthers])
```

But, if I'm using `mixWithOthers`, app stops to receive remote events. That means, that if I want to receive `toggle play/pause` event from headset, I can't use this option:

```
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
```

This is weird, but this is what we have. So in my case I can't use headset buttons :(

Comment: Sadly,it's didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to do your job. App's document can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpremotecommandcenter)

```
MPRemoteCommandCenter.sharedCommandCenter().togglePlayPauseCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(togglePlayStop))
func togglePlayStop(){
    //isPlaying = !isPlaying
}
```

Comment: Yes, I tried this one, but it doesn't trigger also.