# Why is my app not responding to remote control events?

Tags: ios, swift, remote-control, uievent, uicontrolevents

I'm making an app that plays an audio stream on the background when the device is locked. I want the app to respond to the media controls on the lock screen. I followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8518497/7287804) but for some reason I can't make my app respond to these controls. This is the code I have on my View Controller

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
    becomeFirstResponder()
}

override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
    return true
}

override func remoteControlReceived(with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let event = event else { return }
    if event.type == .remoteControl {
        switch event.subtype {
        case .remoteControlTogglePlayPause:
            if player.rate == 0 {
                player.pause()
            } else {
                player.play()
            }
        case .remoteControlPlay:
            player.play()
            break

        case .remoteControlPause:
            player.pause()
            break

        default:
            break
        }
    }
}`
```

Any guidance on what I'm doing wrong will be really appreciated!

Comment: have you set your AVAudioSession category and made it active?

Comment: I did it on the viewDidLoad() 

`override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, with: .mixWithOthers)
            do {
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
`

Comment: Are there any update/reload style functions that you need to call when you change stream properties?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44807532/2303865

Comment: Have you enabled Background Modes Capabilities in info.plist for Audio?

Comment: Thank you everyone, @LeoDabus comment fixed my problem.